# WPF Style behaving strangely

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following `Style` in my App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="BrowseBtn" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Content">
         <Setter.Value>
              <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/BrowseIcon.png" />
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I use this style in a `Window` like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnBrowseCampaigns" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource BrowseBtn}" />
<Button x:Name="btnBrowseDatabase" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource BrowseBtn}" />
```

As you can see, there's no obvious difference between the two buttons, but in the designer (and at runtime), only one of these buttons shows the icon. Is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for Style set `x:Shared="False"` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BrowseBtn"
           x:Shared="True" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/BrowseIcon.jpg" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

When `x:Shared="True"` by default then one Style is common to all - in this case, the system swears on the duplicate `Content`. When `x:Shared="False"` when is created Style for each element whenever it its request. Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When set to *false*, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a `new instance` for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

For more information, please see:

[`MSDN: x:Shared Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: `x:Shared` is not recognized by my VS.

Comment: Also, why would one want this type of style not to be shared?

Comment: @dotNET: Strangely, goes some mistake? VS what version? In my intelesense he does not appear, it is necessary to write in `Style`.

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Express. This is WPF with .NET 4.0 and this is an application-level resource if that has something to do.

Comment: Wow. This actually works, although VS doesn't show intellisense for it.